# Insert an object in a list in chronological order

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a list with objects inside which have a `DateTime` property.
Using a `DataPicker` and a `TimePicker`, I create a `DateTime` object, which I then insert into the `ObservableCollection<>`. However, I would like to insert the elements in the list in chronological order with respect to the `DateTime`. How can I find the right position to put it in the list?

```
 public class HumorDiary
 {
    public DateTime Dt { get; set; }
 }

HumorDiary obj= new HumorDiary();
obj.Dt= xx/xx/xxxx;

ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> listDiario = new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>();
    
listDiario.Insert(Position????, obj);
```

Comment: just sort the list *after* you insert the new object

Comment: listDiario.OrderBy(x => x.Dt); It is ok?

Comment: why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Comparable objects, such as `DateTime` or `string` (as in the duplicate) have a `CompareTo()` method, and `IList<T>` collections such as `ObservableCollection<T>` are amenable to using a binary search (though unlike `List<T>`, ObservableCollection<T>` does not have the method built-in, it's simple enough to implement yourself). You can do a binary search or insertion sort, both of which are described among the answers to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer edited after testing the code.)

You can sort the list yourself.

```
listDario.Add(obj);
listDario = new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>(listDario.OrderBy(x => x.Dt));
```

To my surprise, this does not actually fire an additional `CollectionChanged` event.  However, note that this creates a new list, and event handlers attached to the list will probably be unlinked.  I would also say it's not terribly efficient.  If you don't need the event functionality at all, use `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` instead.

You could also write an extension method like below, but it assumes the list is already sorted, so you'd have to make sure to use it for every insert.

```
    public static void InsertByDate(this ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> source, HumorDiary obj)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        while (idx < source.Count() && source[idx].Dt <= obj.Dt) {
            idx += 1;
        }
        source.Insert(idx, obj);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are more than one methods for achieving this but the simplest one is using `OrderBy`method. Here is an example:

```
        HumorDiary obj1 = new HumorDiary();
        obj1.Dt = DateTime.Now;
        HumorDiary obj2 = new HumorDiary();
        obj2.Dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        HumorDiary obj3 = new HumorDiary();
        obj3.Dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);

        ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> listDiario = new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>();

        listDiario.Add(obj3);
        listDiario.Add(obj2);
        listDiario.Add(obj1);

        listDiario = new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>(listDiario.OrderBy(obj => obj.Dt));
```

Notice that you have to cast iorderedenumerable to ObservableCollection after ordering.

Comment: This answer completely misses the point of using `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is that the collection _notifies_ client code when the collection changes. If you're just going to _replace_ the collection with a whole new collection, there's no reason to use an _observable_ collection in the first place.

Comment: Oh you are right! Thanks for correcting me!